# Embedding React-Redux SPA .NET Core template inside Another HTML page

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, react-redux, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a new project using the React-Redux SPA template for Visual Studio 2017

Now the "react-app" div is added in Index.cshtml.
what if I want to reuse the same `<div>` again inside another app(simp HTML page) and reuse related scripts.
here is what on a test.html page

> scripts

```
<base href="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

> body

```
<div id="react-app" asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server"  data-content="{&quot;formID&quot;:7}">Loading...</div>
```

running this page in browser says that `initialReduxState` is `undefined`.

so what is the best practice to easily embed React component and its related scripts into another page without requiring MVC Razor views?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that the server side prerendering is initiating the `initialReduxState`, and in this case (simple HTML page), server side prerendering is not working and all Tag Helpers like `asp-prerender-module` are useless and should be removed.

so to get the main-client.js file work, I modified boot-client.ts file

from

`const initialState = (window as any).initialReduxState as ApplicationState;`

to

```
const initialState = (window as any).initialReduxState as ApplicationState || { form: {}, routing: { location: null }};
```